# Does Dragula accepts buffer the answer?

Tags: javascript, dragula

I'm using dragula and wanted to have a heading within each container. I've managed to make the heading non-draggable via the `moves` attribute, but, then I also wanted to prohibit that elements can be dropped above the heading so I added:

```
accepts: function (el, target) {
            var itemPos = Array.from(el.parentNode.children).indexOf(el);
            var acceptDrop = itemPos > 0;
            console.log("Accept Drop = " + acceptDrop);
            return acceptDrop;
          },
```

In the console log, I can see that the `acceptDrop` is `false` when I move an element to the first position but the drop is possible anyway! But then I can't move it from that position. I.e. If the accepts returns `false` when the drag is initiated I can't drop the item anywhere, but if it starts with `true` I can drop it everywhere. Am I missing something or how can I make this dynamic and prevent drops at position zero?

(I know that I can put the heading outside the container with draggable items but that needs extra HTML nesting that shouldn't be needed)

Comment: `el` is the element that is being dragged while `target` is where it is going to be dropped if you allow the drop. There are also 3rd and 4th arguments for `accepts` - 4th being the `sibling`. `el` will be dropped inside `target` and before the `sibling`. So you should check whether `sibling` is the first child of `target`.

Comment: Sorry for not connecting back! But thanks for the clear answer! It solved my problems!